# OCCI compilation with g++ in Linux

Tags: c++, oracle, g++, occi

I'm trying to compile a basic program using OCCI library.

The compilation task is OK.

```
g++ -I. -g -I/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/precomp/public -I/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/rdbms/public -I/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/rdbms/demo -I/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/plsql/public -I/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/public -DMAX_SEND_SIZE=2000   -c -o test.o test.cpp
```

the output is OK, test.o is generated. But, when I want to link the object file, with the following command,

```
g++ -L/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib/ -lclntsh -locci -o test test.o
```

The linking task fails, the output is:

```
 test.o: In function `main':
/home/xxx/occi/test.cpp:128: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned int), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned int), void (*)(void*, void*))'
/home/xxx/occi/test.cpp:170: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)'
/home/xxx/occi/test.cpp:158: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::SQLException::~SQLException()'
/home/xxx/occi/test.cpp:158: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::SQLException::SQLException(oracle::occi::SQLException const&)'
/home/xxx/occi/test.cpp:163: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::SQLException::what() const'
/home/xxx/occi/test.cpp:158: undefined reference to `oracle::occi::SQLException::~SQLException()'
test.o:(.gcc_except_table+0xe0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for oracle::occi::SQLException'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My environment resume:

- Ubuntu Linux 11.04
- gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
- ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1
- LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib
- Oracle version: 10.2.0

Can you help me please?, I really need to create a connection to Oracle using OCCI in Linux and I don't want to use Pro*C.

Comment: Have you tried changing the library include order in the link step? This can be important.

Comment: yes, I tried, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

To use OCCI you need to install Instant Client provided by Oracle (have you installed?). I'm using Oracle 11.2, so my include directory path is /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 and my share libraries is /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib.

I saw here

```
http://173.255.217.246:8000/mapnik_trac/wiki/OCCI
```

that 10.2 path is /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/include and /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib

In 11.2, I also need to link with nnz11 lib first as http://xme.im/connect-oracle-database-eclipse-linux-using-occi

This is an usefull blog describe about Instant Client http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-started-with-occi-linux-version.html